# PC Building, can't proceed into BIOS, error screen

Tags: bios, sata

I'm a first time PC builder and I've put together a PC but when I power it up I come to this screen and can't proceed any further.
[image: Screenshot of error screen]

I'm not sure what it all means and any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your error says you can not plug an m.2 drive (your samsung ssd) into that slot.  Does your motherboard support m.2?

Comment: Motherboard is ASUS PRIME Z270-AR ATX and has two M.2 ports

Comment: You've put a SATA M.2 device in the M.2 Socket, you need to use an NMVe device in that socket.  See here: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2776112/clarification-terminology-ssd-pcie-nvme.html

Answer (score 3):

As Dave Lucre has pointed out, you put Samsung 850 M.2 which works on SATA mode. The error message you got points out exactly that (you put a SATA M.2 into the PCIe M.2)

Luckily your motherboard have support for both:
1 x M.2 Socket 3, , with M Key, type 2242/2260/2280/22110 storage devices support (SATA mode & X4 PCIE mode)*1
1 x M.2 Socket 3, , with M Key, type 2242/2260/2280 storage devices support (PCIE mode only)*2

So simply move your current Samsung 850 M.2 card into the other M.2 slot and you will be fine.

Ref: [ASUS Prime Z270-AR](https://www.asus.com/au/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-AR/specifications/)